# Dirichlet unit theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Say that, by Dirichlet unit theorem, we have an isomorphism $$\mathscr{O}_K^\times=\langle \pm 1\rangle \times \langle r_1\rangle.$$
Why is this equivalent to saying that every unit $x$ in $\mathscr{O}_K$ can be written as $x=\pm r^{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Also, is it sufficient in this case, to find the fundamental unit $r_1$,  to find a unit with infinite order?

Comment: How do you know you haven't merely found a power of the fundamental unit?

Comment: @JWTanner ah yes , of course.. :(

Comment: @JWTanner but is the first statement true ?

Comment: Yes, $\langle r_1\rangle = \{1, r_1, r_1^2, r_1^3...\}$, so $\langle \pm 1 \rangle \times \langle r_1 \rangle = \{\pm1, \pm r_1, \pm r_1^2, \pm r_1^3,...\}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Don't forget about the negative powers of $r_1$.

Comment: And why is this ? The direct product consists of tuples right ? so it would be $(\pm 1,r_1^k)$ ? I don't understand the isomorphism with the unit group, why is this canonical ?

Comment: Presumably $K$ is real? Otherwise, you could have other roots of unity. To answer your question, how are you actually defining the isomorphism between $\mathcal O_K^{\times}$ and the direct product? Surely the only natural map from right to left is the one that sends $r_1\mapsto r_1$ and $\pm1\mapsto\pm1$. The rest follows from the properties of group isomorphisms.